# Host PHP application on IIS and then DB driver error

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have a PHP application that is already hosted on Windows IIS Server.But when i try to run it now then it shows me the error."db driver not found".BUT i have installed [Microsoft Drivers 5.6 for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57916) .But still getting error.I'm using **SQL Server Express 14.0.1000.169** version.

Is this a correct driver version to download ? or what is the error?.
[image]

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Also, why are you using the RTM version of SQL Server 2017? Why haven't you patched in over 2 years? The version you are using has **known** security flaws.

Comment: Have you checked whether your PHP version are supported by latest driver? It looks like an compatibility issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

firstly, are you sure you chose the correct dll for your computer to be the php extension?  version, thread safety, system architecture.  All of these matter.  If that is correct then you can move on to the next step which are drivers.